# Fallback font-file in Android

Tags: android, fonts, internationalization, font-family, glyph

I'm developing a multi-language application. I need to handle chars in Japanese and English but the application font has only Roman glyphs.

I'd like to define a font-family or similar in Android (and use the API 26 support library) so I can define:

MyFontFamily:

- use `font-company.otf` (company font, for Roman chars)
- use `font-fallback.otf` (it contains a wide range of language support)

Does something like this exist in Android without resorting to manually setting each TypefaceSpan?